# IllegalArgumentException error with snmpget

Tags: java, jlist, snmp4j

I have a jlist for IP addresses and a method  to save the selected value from the jlist

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){
        s=(String)list.getSelectedValue(); 
    }
});
```

I set the button listener

```
infoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        SNMP client = new SNMP();
        client.snmpGet(ServerFrame.s,"COMMUNAUTE_SERVEUR",".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
        client.snmpGet(ServerFrame.s,"COMMUNAUTE_SERVEUR","1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0");
        client.snmpGet(ServerFrame.s,"COMMUNAUTE_SERVEUR",".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0");
    }
});
```

This line `client.snmpGet(ServerFrame.s,"COMMUNAUTE_SERVEUR",".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");` causes this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 192.168.1.64  /161
>   at org.snmp4j.smi.UdpAddress.(Unknown Source)

This is the `snmpget` method that i call in the button listener

```
public String snmpGet(String host, String community, String strOID) {
    String strResponse="";
    ResponseEvent response;
    Snmp snmp;
    try {
        OctetString community1 = new OctetString(community);
        host= host+"/"+"161";
        Address tHost = new UdpAddress(host);
        TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        transport.listen();
        CommunityTarget comtarget = new CommunityTarget();
        comtarget.setCommunity(community1);
        comtarget.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
        comtarget.setAddress(tHost);
        comtarget.setRetries(2);
        comtarget.setTimeout(5000);
        PDU pdu = new PDU();
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(strOID)));
        pdu.setType(PDU.GET); 
        snmp = new Snmp(transport);
        response = snmp.get(pdu,comtarget);
        if(response != null) {
            if(response.getResponse().getErrorStatusText().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {
                PDU pduresponse=response.getResponse();
                strResponse=pduresponse.getVariableBindings().firstElement().toString();
                if(strResponse.contains("=")) {
                    String strNewResponse = null;
                    int len = strResponse.indexOf("=");
                    strNewResponse=strResponse.substring(len+1, strResponse.length());
                    System.out.println("The SNMP response to the OID requested is: " + strNewResponse);
                }
            }
    } else {
            System.out.println("Looks like a TimeOut occured ");
    }
        snmp.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println("Response="+strResponse);
    return strResponse;
}
```

Any help with this error, i get, the problem seems to be with the s variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just me or does the IllegalArgumentException show an extra space in your IP address:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 192.168.1.64 /161

Try adding a .trim() call to remove extra whitespace:

Change

```
host= host+"/"+"161";
```

to

```
host= host.trim() + "/" + 161;
```

And see if that avoids the IllegalArgumentException